# What can I use in eventtriggers.exe place on Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I would like an alert to either be shown on the screen or to be emailed when a particular event is logged on a Windows 2008 R2 server. I understand that eventtriggers.exe has been deprecated however am unable to find a replacement for it on Windows 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly certain that 'Task Scheduler' MMC was the replacement for eventtriggers. For instance if you have an EventID you can use that as a trigger and the action will be to send an e-mail. This kind of gives you an overview: [Example](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/explore-new-task-scheduler-triggers-in-windows-server-2008/362)